# PHP: is there a difference between (isset($a) && !empty($a)) and $a??false

Tags: php

I inherited a codebase that is filled with conditionals using terms like `(isset($a) && !empty($a))` but the `$a` are actually long variable names and it's an eye-sore.  I wanted to replace the expressions with `$a??false` but I wasn't sure if there was some case that wouldn't be the same.

Are these statements identical or is there some value of $a that would be different?

Comment: `isset($a) && !empty($a)` is __redundant__. Just `!empty($a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's understand what the different elements are doing:

- `isset` takes a variable, array element, etc, and returns **true** if it **exists**, and has **any value other than null**
- `empty` takes a variable, array element, etc, and returns **false** if it **exists**, and **has any value which would be considered equivalent to `true`**
- `??` examines a variable, array element, etc, and returns **its value** if it **exists**, and has **any value other than null**; otherwise, it returns **its right-hand argument**
- any expression used in an `if` statement is cast to boolean automatically

So, we can look at the equivalences:

- `empty` is a combination of `isset()` and a cast to false; specifically, `empty($a) === !isset($a) || !(bool)$a`, so `!empty($a) === isset($a) && (bool)$a`
- `??` uses the same check as `isset`, not the same check as `empty`; so `$a ?? false` on its own is equivalent to `isset($a) ? $a : false`
- *but*, in an `if` statement, the whole thing will be forced to boolean, so `if ( $a ?? false ) ...` is equivalent to `if ( (bool)(isset($a) ? $a : false) ) ...` or more readably `if ( isset($a) ? (bool)$a : false ) ...`

Which brings us to the answer, which is that the following all do the same thing:

```
if ( isset($a) && !empty($a) ) ...
if ( isset($a) && !(bool)$a ) ... // empty() is just a bool cast + isset
if ( !empty($a) ) ... // the isset is actually redundant
if ( isset($a) ? (bool)$a : false ) ... // same logic as the && version
if ( (bool)($a ?? false) ) ... // ?? does the isset for us
if ( $a ?? false ) ... // if does the (bool) for us
```

Probably the most readable is just to use `!empty($a)` on its own, and leave `??` for where you actually need the original value rather than a `true`.

Comment: Just to note that `if ( !empty($a) )` is equivalent to `if ( $a )` if the variable `$a` can be proven to exist in the current scope.